# Discord.py - Member fetching in Cog

Tags: python, class, bots, discord, discord.py

I have problem with fetching server members in cog. (fetch_members())

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Guild(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(discord.Guild.fetch_members(self))

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Guild(client))
```

This client is bot itself. I want to get list of members on server, but I get error

`AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute '_state'`

I don't know how and where to get this state and what it is. Didn't find it in documentation. I am very new to python and don't know much about it's classes.

Even if I try to do it in main bot file like in documentation, it still not working, so i came up that this must be in cog file.

Maybe you know how to do it another way. Any help is welcome !

Comment: `discord.Guild` is a class, i think you should use `self.client.guilds` to get guild list.

Comment: Thanks ! I used discord.Guilds class instead of client.guilds. Thanks for marking !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [document](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_members#discord.Guild.fetch_members), you should use this method directly to guild instance. I rewrite your code like this:

```py
class Guild(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        for guild in self.client.guilds:
            print(f'In {guild.name}')
            async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=5):
                print(member.name)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Guild(client))
```

Since your bot may join many guilds, `client.guilds` is a list that you need to use for-loop to iterate. The `discord.Guild` is a class, and the object in `client.guilds` is the instance of this class, most of the behavior can only be used on the instance.

Comment: Wow Thanks ! Really helped me out ) I haven't used client.guilds, that's why I was stuck.